# Hive View Not Opening

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

In the Ambari UI of the hortonworks sandbox, I was trying to open Hive View through the account of maria_dev. But however, I was getting the following error:

```
Service Hive check failed: 
Cannot open a hive connection with connect string 
jdbc:hive2://sandbox-hdp.hortonworks.com:2181/;serviceDiscoveryMode=zooKeeper;zooKeeperNamespace=hiveserver2;hive.server2.proxy.user=maria_dev
```

Can someone please help me sort out the error?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to rectify the issue, although I was unable to understand why such a problem cropped up. I was using the  `hadoop ecosystem`  in a docker. I just stopped, removed and re-started the sandbox-hdp. After re-starting  `hive view`  was working just fine. But however, I am still getting the following error :

```
unable to load database password
```

If someone could clarify, it would be really great. :) :)

Comment: I ran the following commands and checked :

echo "bigdata" > /etc/ambari-server/conf/password.dat and then 
ambari-server restart ............These worked out for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hive reads some configurations from zookeeper and I was able to resolve the issue simply by restarting the Zoo keeper.